# BubbleSort Algorithm Returning Undesired Results

Tags: java, bubble-sort

Here is my implementation of the bubble sort algorithm.

```
 import java.util.Arrays;

 public class BubbleSort {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] unsorted = {1,3,5,6,2};
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(unsorted));
        bubbleSort(unsorted);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(unsorted));
    }

    public static void bubbleSort(int[] unsorted){
        int i;
        int j;
        int temp;
        for (i = 0; i < unsorted.length; i++) {
            for (j = 1; j < unsorted.length-1; j++) {
                if (unsorted[i] > unsorted[j]) {
                    temp = unsorted[i];
                    unsorted[i] = unsorted[j];
                   unsorted[j] = temp;
                 }
             }
        }
   }
 }
```

Here is the output:

```
[1, 3, 5, 6, 2]
[1, 6, 5, 3, 2]
```

This is clearly wrong, but my logic seems alright.

Comment: Your second loop should start `for (j = i+1; ...`

Comment: doing that outputs the same unsorted array
[1, 3, 5, 6, 2]
[1, 3, 5, 6, 2]

Comment: Get rid of the -1 on the same line

Comment: The stop condition in the second loop should be changed from: `j < unsorted.length-1` to: `j < unsorted.length`

Comment: ok that worked....now i need to understand why that worked

Comment: change the second loop from `j = 1` to `j=0`

Comment: @MarrieteCowby12 I'm afraid that's wrong.

Comment: @michael please explain why? I tested it and it produced a sorted array from high to low

Comment: have you tried debugging  your code by your self ???

Comment: @MarrieteCowby12 Sorry, for some reason I thought that wouldn't work. In fact, what you posted would be a "traditional" bubble sort, and the one I suggested is just a slight optimisation.

Comment: @MarrieteCowby12 If in the second loop j=0 wouldn't that be the same as i=0 since they both mean unsorted[0]. I am just now learning coding and things are a bit confusing for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of your problems are with this line:

```
for (j = 1; j < unsorted.length-1; j++) {
```

You don't want to loop from the first element, you want to loop from the first element after i:

```
for (j = i+1; j < unsorted.length-1; j++) {
```

You also need to go all the way to the end:

```
for (j = i+1; j < unsorted.length; j++) {
```

Comment: Can you help me understand why looping from j=1 is different from j=i+1. Since j=1 means it starts looping from the second value of the array, which should be fine too.

Comment: On the first iteration of the outer loop they are identical - so you're half right! However, **on subsequent iterations of the outer loop**, in your example J is always equal to 1. In my example, first J is equal to 1, then 2, then 3 and so on.

Comment: @user3059625 so if you say `j=1` instead of `j=i+1`, you are saying that even when you are at `i=3`, `j=1` instead of `j=4`. Since you are doing nested for loops, it might be easy to confuse but you are doing an iteration through the inner for loop and then incrementing `i`. The first time through, you are guaranteed that the first value of the array is the lowest as long as your logic is correct, therefore i gets incremented and you don't need to worry about it. and you can worry about the next values.

Comment: Thanks Michael and Orin, I see the difference crystal clear now. :)

Answer (score 1):

A few things 
1) you can declare i and j within the loop scope
2) try to keep it consistent both iterations 0 -> length
3) the less then sign in i < unsorted.length will make sure that you do not go past the index bounds. because array indexes range from 0 to length-1.
4) your swap logic is great the only thing that needed attention was the loop range.
5) unsorted[i] < unsorted[j] will determine which way the order will go.

```
public static void bubbleSort(int[] unsorted) {
    for (int i = 0; i < unsorted.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < unsorted.length; j++) {
            if (unsorted[i] < unsorted[j]) {
                int temp = unsorted[i];
                unsorted[i] = unsorted[j];
                unsorted[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
here is the correct code

> import java.util.Arrays;

 public class BubbleSort {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] unsorted = {1,3,5,6,2};
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(unsorted));
        bubbleSort(unsorted);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(unsorted));
    }

    public static void bubbleSort(int[] unsorted){
        int i;
        int j;
        int temp;
        for (i = 0; i < unsorted.length-1; i++) {
            for (j = i+1; j < unsorted.length; j++) {
                if (unsorted[i] > unsorted[j]) {
                    temp = unsorted[i];
                    unsorted[i] = unsorted[j];
                   unsorted[j] = temp;
                 }
             }
        }
   }
 }

the second loop begins after i so j alway start at i+1 and end at unsorted.length while i end at unsorted.length-1
```

[image: here is the result I got when I ran this code]

Comment: While this is correct, try to do a more in-depth explanation of why it works this way. Just giving the answer doesn't help OP learn anything, and if he doesn't learn anything he will always come to SO for answers. :)

Comment: Ok this algorithm take the first element (i) in the table, the start moving from the next element on (j) , looking for a number greater than the first one. that's why i goes till unsorted.length-1 because if you reach the end of the table the j will be no more in the table. the i move to the second element because after the first loop, the first elelent is already at it place so no need to come on it anymore and so on

Answer (score 0):

I have saved bubble sort algorithm in my computer, is this (without copy to a new array):

```
public static void bubbleSort (int[] v) {
      for (int i=0; i<v.length-1; i++)
         for (int j=v.length-1; j>i; j--)
            if (v[j-1]>v[j]) {
               int aux = v[j-1];
               v[j-1] = v[j];
               v[j] = aux;   
            }
   }
```